# What is the probability that she got one chocolate of each variety (Milky Way, Almond Joy, Butterfinger, Nestle Crunch, Snickers, and Kit Kat)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The first part of the question is also here [Probability/Combinatorics Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380485/probability-combinatorics-question)

> At a picnic, there was a bowl of chocolate candy that had 10 pieces of Milky Way, Almond Joy, Butterfinger, Nestle Crunch, Snickers, and Kit Kat.  Jen grabbed six pieces at random from this bowl of 60 chocolate candies.
>
> (a)  What is the probability that she got one of each variety?

My approach was- let the variable $x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_6$ denote the number of candies of first type, second type and so on..

Thus total number of ways in which Jen could take out the candies would be equal to the number of positive integral solutions of

$$x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_6=6$$

which is ${6+5}\choose  {5}$
And only one configuration ($x_1=x_2=\cdots =x_6=1$) is favourable.

Thus the probability is $$\frac{1}{{6+5}\choose  {5}}$$ But this answer doesn't match with the answer given in the linked question .

Where am I going wrong ?

**Edit**: I understand most answers are claiming that all integer solutions are not 'equally likely', this somehow presupposes that one choice of the probability measure is correct over the other, eg: I could have defined the probability measure such that each integer solution is equally likely. Is there any reason to chose one measure over the other?

Answer (score 2):

Addendum just added to respond to questions from the Original Poster.

---

As other answers have indicated, while it is true that there are $\binom{11}{5}$ non-negative integer solutions to

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 6$,

these solutions are not equally likely.

Let's consider $3$ such solutions: I will use the syntax $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ to indicate that

$x_1 = a, x_2 = b, x_3 = c, x_4 = d, x_5 = e, x_6 = f.$

---

Solution 1: (3,2,1,0,0,0).

There are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways that $3$ of the 1st type of candy could be selected.

There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways that $2$ of the 2nd type of candy could be selected.

There are $\binom{10}{1}$ ways that $1$ of the 3rd type of candy could be selected.

Computation equals $\binom{10}{3} \times \binom{10}{2} \times \binom{10}{1}.$

---

Solution 2: (2,2,2,0,0,0).

There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways that $2$ of the 1st type of candy could be selected.

There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways that $2$ of the 2nd type of candy could be selected.

There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways that $2$ of the 3rd type of candy could be selected.

Computation equals $\binom{10}{2} \times \binom{10}{2} \times \binom{10}{2}.$

---

Solution 3: (1,1,1,1,1,1).

There are $\binom{10}{1}$ ways that $1$ of the 1st type of candy could be selected.

There are $\binom{10}{1}$ ways that $1$ of the 2nd type of candy could be selected.

There are $\binom{10}{1}$ ways that $1$ of the 3rd type of candy could be selected.

There are $\binom{10}{1}$ ways that $1$ of the 4th type of candy could be selected.

There are $\binom{10}{1}$ ways that $1$ of the 5th type of candy could be selected.

There are $\binom{10}{1}$ ways that $1$ of the 6th type of candy could be selected.

Computation equals $\binom{10}{1}^6.$

---

My solution:

Probability equals $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}$$

Where $D = \binom{60}{6} = $ the number of ways of selecting $6$ candies out of $60$.  Here:

- The selection is without replacement.
- The order that the candies are selected is not deemed relevant.

Because of the second point above, the numerator, $N$ must be enumerated in a consistent manner.  That means that when enumerating $N$, you must presume that the order that the candies where selected is irrelevant.

Suppose that the candies were numbered $1,2,\cdots,60$, where :

- Candies $1$ through $10$ were Milky Way.
- Candies $11$ through $20$ were Almond Joy.
- Candies $21$ through $30$ were Butterfinger.
- Candies $31$ through $40$ were Nestle Crunch.
- Candies $41$ through $50$ were Snickers.
- Candies $51$ through $60$ were Kit Kat.

There are $\binom{10}{1} = 10$ choices for which Milky Way candy is selected.

Independently, regardless of which Milky Way candy is selected, there are $\binom{10}{1} = 10$ choices for which Almond Joy candy is selected.

The same type of reasoning indicates that you will have $6$ independent factors to consider:  that is, for each type of candy, there are $(10)$ choices for which candy is selected.

In other words, you have $10$ choices for which Milky Way is selected, $10$ choices for which Almond Joy is selected, $10$ choices for which Butterfinger is selected, and so forth.

Therefore, $N = \binom{10}{1}^6 = \left(10\right)^6.$

---

Final computation:

$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{(10)^6}{\binom{60}{6}}.$$

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the OP's comment and the latest editing of his question.

> I actually was looking for an explanation of why they are not equally...

> I understand most answers are claiming that all integer solutions are not 'equally likely', this somehow presupposes that one choice of the probability measure is correct over the other, eg: I could have defined the probability measure such that each integer solution is equally likely. Is there any reason to chose one measure over the other?

In order to explore these issues, I will first try to examine in greater detail, each of the $\binom{11}{5} = 462$ solutions to the equation

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 6 \tag1 $$
$$~~: ~x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.  $$

I will partition the solutions into all of the possible formats.  For each individual solution that corresponds to a specific format, I will determine how many distinct distributions are represented by this solution.  Then the probability will be computed as

$$\frac{\text{# of satisfying distributions}}{\text{total # of possible distributions}}.$$

I will use the syntax $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ to indicate that

$x_1 = a, x_2 = b, x_3 = c, x_4 = d, x_5 = e, x_6 = f.$

For a solution that follows format $k$, as detailed below, I will use the variable $t_k$ to denote how many of the $(462)$ solutions have format $k$.

I will then use the variable $w_k$ to denote how many different distributions are associated with  each individual solution to (1) above that follows format $k$.

In effect, $w_k$, which denotes a number of distributions, will be used to represent a **weight** that is given to each of the solutions represented by format $k$.  In effect, $w_k$ will represent the **relative weight** to be given to each of the $462$ solutions, based on how many distributions are associated with the specific solution.

This implies that the product $(t_k \times w_k)$ will represent all of the distributions possible that are represented by format $k$.

The following table examines each of the possible formats:

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |r |}
  \hline                       
  \text{#} & \text{Pattern} & t_k 
& w_k & t_k \times w_k \\
  \hline                       
  1 & (6,0,0,0,0,0) & 6 & \binom{10}{6} & 1,260 \\
\hline 
  2 & (5,1,0,0,0,0) & 30 & \binom{10}{5} \times \binom{10}{1} & 75,600 \\
  \hline 
  3 & (4,2,0,0,0,0) & 30 & \binom{10}{4} \times \binom{10}{2} & 283,500 \\
  \hline  
  4 & (4,1,1,0,0,0) & 60 & \binom{10}{4} \times \binom{10}{1}^2 & 1,260,000 \\
  \hline  
  5 & (3,3,0,0,0,0) & 15 & \binom{10}{3}^2 & 216,000 \\
  \hline  
  6 & (3,2,1,0,0,0) & 120 & \binom{10}{3} \times \binom{10}{2} \times \binom{10}{1} & 6,480,000 \\
  \hline  
  7 & (3,1,1,1,0,0) & 60 & \binom{10}{3} \times \binom{10}{1}^3 & 7,200,000 \\
  \hline  
  8 & (2,2,2,0,0,0) & 20 & \binom{10}{2}^3 & 1,822,500 \\
  \hline  
  9 & (2,2,1,1,0,0) & 90 & \binom{10}{2}^2 \times \binom{10}{1}^2 & 18,225,000 \\
  \hline   
  10 & (2,1,1,1,1,0) & 30 & \binom{10}{2} \times \binom{10}{1}^4 & 13,500,000 \\
  \hline  
  11 & (1,1,1,1,1,1) & 1 & \binom{10}{1}^6 & 1,000,000 \\
  \hline 
  \text{sum} & & 462 & & 50,063,860 \\
  \hline   
\end{array}

Notice that $\sum_{k=1}^{11} t_k = 462 = \binom{11}{5}.$

Notice that $\sum_{k=1}^{11} (t_k \times w_k) = 50,063,860 = \binom{60}{6}.$

This means that in the above chart, all of the $\binom{11}{5}$ possible solutions are accounted for and all of the $\binom{60}{6}$ possible distributions are accounted for.

Then, the probability of a satisfying distribution is

$$\frac{t_{11} \times w_{11}}{\sum_{k=1}^{11} (t_k \times w_k)} = \frac{1,000,000}{50,063,860} = \frac{10^6}{\binom{60}{6}}.$$

For illustrative purposes, I will discuss Format # $7$ in greater detail.

There are $6$ choices for which of the $6$ variables will be set to the value $(3)$.  Once this selection is made, there are $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways of selecting $3$ of the remaining $5$ variables, and then setting these variables to the value $(1)$.

Therefore, $t_7 = 6 \times 10 = 60.$

For each of the $60$ out of a possible $462$ solutions to the equation $x_1 + \cdots + x_6 = 6$, how many distributions are represented by each solution?  To answer that, simply determine how many distributions are represented by the specific solution $(3,1,1,1,0,0)$.

This solution calls for $3$ candies to be selected from the $10$ candies represented by the candy type associated with the variable $x_1$.  This can be done in $\binom{10}{3}$ ways.

Similarly, there are $\binom{10}{1}$ possible ways of selecting $1$ candy out of $10$, for each of the candy types represented by the variables $x_2, x_3, x_4.$

This explains the value of $w_7$, shown in the chart, and explains the product $(t_7 \times w_7)$ shown in the chart.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I actually was looking for an explanation of why they are not equally likely, please look at the edit I have added to the end of the question.

Comment: @Soham See the Addendum that I just added to my answer, and then leave a message here, if any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's note that in order to get one of every type of the candies, we need to calculate the probability step by step, and also take into consideration the fact that the order doesn't matter (meaning it doesn't matter if we first take out a Milky Way and then a Kit Kat, or any other permutation).

We will choose a first candy, and we do not care what this is. We have ${60}\choose{1}$=60 different ways to choose this first candy.

For the second candy, we now only have 59 candies in the box, and 9 of those candies are the same type as the first one, and therefore, we cannot choose out of those 9 candies, meaning, that we have 50 different choices.

We go on in this manner in order to determine in how many possible ways we can choose 1 of each type. Let's note that this calculation doesn't consider the order of the choice of candies, as we hoped. I'll leave this to you.

Afterwards, we calculate the numbers of ways to choose 6 pieces of candy out of 60 pieces, when we have 10 of each type. This number is $\frac{{60}\choose{6}}{10!^6}$, since we have 6 different types, and 10 identical items in every type.

Comment: I don't see how this clarifies my doubt..

Comment: Sorry, I was just presenting a method for a solution. The problem with your method is that you didn't take into consideration the fact that you remove every candy that you choose out of the box.

Comment: But i can take 6 candies out together, i have really large palms..

Comment: Of course, but usually when questions are stated like this in combinatorics and probability, the intention is that candies are taken out one by one.

Comment: `grabbed six pieces at random` seems to imply all at once.

Comment: and I think every intentions must be clearly stated ..

Comment: The probability does not depend on whether we pick one at a time or grab $6$ at once.

Comment: Early on in the discussion, you have the idea behind a correct solution. The probability all the candies are of different kinds is $\frac{50}{59}\cdot \frac{40}{58}\cdot \frac{30}{57}\cdot \frac{20}{56}\cdot \frac{10}{55}$. If you like, you can put a decorative $\frac{60}{60}$ in front.

Answer (score 0):

In the question you linked the OP seems to have solved it by assuming each chocolate to be different. So there are ten types of Kit-kats, ten types of Milky-ways and so on. Hence there are $60$ different candies and choosing $6$ out of them results in $\binom{60}{6}$ ways.

What you seem to have done is assume that candies of one kind are identical. That is, the ten  Kit-kats are identical and so on. With that assumption, your answer is correct.

However if you ask me, the way the question is phrased, I would accept your assumption as the more appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your argument is that it assumes that every configuration has an equal chance of occurring. For example, your argument assumes that the probability that you pick six snickers is just as likely as the chance that you pick one candy of each type. However, that's not the case.

Think of there being a set $S$ of $60$ candies, separated into $6$ groups of $10$, where candies of the same group are considered the same type. The ways Jen can pick six candies are represented as size-$6$ subsets of $S$. The number of ways to pick six snickers is ${10 \choose 6}=210$. The number of ways to pick one candy of each type is $10^6$. The latter configuration is much more likely to be chosen, so thinking of the probability in terms of configurations is wrong. Instead, we just count the subsets. There are $10^6$ subsets of $S$ consisting of a candy of each type, and ${60\choose 6}$ size-$6$ subsets of $S$ in total, so the probability is $$\frac{10^6}{\binom{60}{6}}$$ as given.

### A smaller example

Say there are $4$ candy bars, labeled $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, all considered distinct. If you pick $2$ at random, what is the probability that you pick $A$ and $B$? If we assume that "at random" means with uniform randomness, then there are $6$ ways to pick $2$ candy bars, and each has an equal chance of occurring. These $6$ ways are $\{A, B\}, \{A, C\}, \{A, D\}, \{B, C\}, \{B, D\},$ and $\{C, D\}$. Hence, there is a $1/6$ chance that we pick $A$ and $B$.

Now say that we find out that $A$ and $B$ both contains marshmallow, and $C$ and $D$ both contains nougat. Now we can think of there just being two marshmallow bars and two nougat bars. What is the probability that we pick two marshmallow bars? Well, it's the same as the probability that we pick $A$ and $B$. Nothing changed about the probabilities of picking combinations of candies when we added in the marshmallow and nougat, it just changed how we viewed the outcomes. We still have $6$ outcomes: $\{A, B\}, \{A, C\}, \{A, D\}, \{B, C\}, \{B, D\},$ and $\{C, D\}$. The difference is that we now view them in terms of marshmallow and nougat. These $6$ outcomes become, respectively, $\{M, M\}, \{M, N\}, \{M, N\}, \{M, N\}, \{M, N\},$ and $\{N, N\}$, where $M$ is marshmallow and $N$ is nougat. There is still a $1/6$ probability that we pick $A$ and $B$. Similarly, there is still a $1/6$ probability that we pick any other outcome. Since $\{M, N\}$ corresponds to $4$ different outcomes, the probability that we pick $\{M, N\}$ is $4/6=2/3$. Your argument says that there are $3$ outcomes: $\{M, M\}, \{M, N\}$, and $\{N, N\}$, and each has $1/3$ chance of occurring, but that is not consistent with the case that all candy bars are treated as distinct.

The underlying issue here is that whether or not we treat all $10$ candies of the same type to be the same, there are still $60$ distinct candies, and the number of ways we can pick six of them is still ${60\choose 6}$. For the purpose of the question, we treat all ten snickers as being the same, but that does not change the fact that those are ten different candies in the bag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I actually was looking for an explanation of why they are not equally likely, please look at the edit I have added to the end of the question.

Comment: @Soham The problem is that you're not choosing an integer solution to that equation, you're choosing six candies, and those six candies determine an integer solution to the equation. The probability still occurs on the level of choosing the candies.

Comment: @Soham If we have $60$ candies, and treat them all as distinct, how many ways are there to choose $6$ of them? ${60\choose 6}$. Now say we put these candies in $6$ different wrappers so that there are $10$ of each. There are still ${60\choose 6}$ ways to pick $6$ candies. What changes is that we may decide to treat all candies of the same wrapper to be the same. If we make that choice, then some of ${60\choose 6}$ subsets will count as the same solution. However, those different solutions will have different probabilities because they correspond to varying numbers of subsets.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use Laplace rule and a tree diagram.

1 st draw -> 60 out of 60 (Milky Way, Almond Joy, Butterfinger, Nestle Crunch, Snickers or Kit Kat)

2 nd draw -> 50/59 (let's fix Milky Way for the previous draw, it can be any other)

3 rd draw -> 40/58 (let's fix Milky Way and Almond Joy, it can be any two pair)

4 th draw -> 30/57

5 th draw -> 20/56

6 th draw -> 10/55

Now we multiply (10*20*30*40*50*60)/(55*56*57*58*59*60) -> p = 0.01997448858

In percentage close to a 2% chance.

Comment: (10 x 20 x 30 x 40 x 50 x 60)/(55 x 56 x 57 x 58 x 59 x 60) = 0.01997448858

Answer (score 0):

As you say, there are ${6+5\choose 6}={11\choose 6}=462$ possible positive integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+...+x_6=6$.

Your edit then states:  "I understand most answers are claiming that all integer solutions are not 'equally likely', this somehow presupposes that one choice of the probability measure is correct over the other, eg: I could have defined the probability measure such that each integer solution is equally likely. Is there any reason to chose one measure over the other?"

I believe the problem is that you did define the probability measure such that each integer solution is equally likely, and this is why the solution doesn't work out.

Consider the number of ways to have one of each:  ${5\choose 1}^6=5^6=15,625$.  Then consider the number of ways to have two of the first three:  ${5\choose 2}^3*{5\choose 0}^3=1,000$.  Based on this counting, it is over 15 times more likely to choose one of each candy than it is to choose 2 of the first three candies.  However, both possibilities represent one possible positive integer solution each to $x_1+x_2+...+x_6=6$.